# How can I manage all my Ruby gems as Ubuntu packages?

Tags: package-management, ruby, gem

Whenever I have to install Ruby software on our Ubuntu based webserver, I run into a new `gem` package manager problem that I never saw with Ubuntu packages. By now I really hate it, and got the idea that maybe I could install and manage my gems as Ubuntu packages instead?

But I did not find a solution so far:

- The offcial gems repository is [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/), and it contains [~155,000 gems](https://rubygems.org/stats). In contrast, there are [about 1300 `ruby-*` Ubuntu packages](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=ruby-). So a lot of gems will be missing.
- I could also not find a PPA that would provide one Ubuntu package per gem, or something close to that.
- I found however [instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Ruby/Packaging) for packaging a gem as a `.deb` package, including a binary `gem2deb` that does much of that work.

My ideal solution would be something like [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) but for Ruby gems. Commands would look like this (completely hypothetical for now):

```
gemcheckinstall gem install <gemname>

gemcheckinstall bundle install
```

They would create Ubuntu packages from all requested gems and also install them. Any ideas for a technique / workflow, perhaps with `gem2deb`?